# LINQ - Joining 3 tables and selecting an item with two lists

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, group-by

I have a Company table that is linked to Address and Contact tables. There can be multiple Addresses and Contacts for a Company.

I'm joining them with LINQ and using a GroupBy to group by the company, but I'm not sure how to get the list of Addresses and Contacts from it. The only examples I've seen are just trying to get one list for the Key.

How do I write the Select to grab the single Company with a list of Addresses and a list of Contacts?

Below is what I have so far:

```
var companiesList = 
    (from company in _context.Company
        join address in _context.Address
        on company.CompanyId equals address.CompanyId
        join contact in _context.Contact
        on company.CompanyId equals contact.CompanyId
        select new { company, address, contact })
    .GroupBy(x => x.company)
    .Select(group => new {
        Company = group.Key,
        Addresses = ??,
        Contacts = ??
    })
    .AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: You want the join on company of two aggregations on company. Write the aggregations. That gives you info per company. Join them. PS This is surely a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Now googling 'two aggregations different columns linq site:stackoverflow.com'....

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close to the answer. You can use

```
group.ToList().Select(c=>c.address),
```

and

```
group.ToList().Select(c=>c.contact)
```

Complete example

```
var companiesList  =  (from company in _context.Company
        join address in _context.Address
        on company.CompanyId equals address.CompanyId
        join contact in _context.Contact
        on company.CompanyId equals contact.CompanyId
        select new { company, address, contact })
    .GroupBy(x => x.company)
    .Select(group => new {
        Company = group.Key,
        Addresses = group.ToList().Select(c=>c.address),
        Contacts = group.ToList().Select(c=>c.contact)
    })
```